# How can I save an email from Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

How can I save a complete email from Thunderbird to a file in Home? I have tried draging and copying without success.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try to use File -> Save As -> ... or Ctrl + S?

Comment: Tried both  SaveAs and Ctl S but only get  the "note pad" data, not the full HMTL. the save is like this:

Comment: Under places, change All Files to HTML please.

Comment: @ronfreeland, save saves the whole email, whether it is plain text or html, or both.

Comment: Thanks, by changing the file extension from .eml to.hmtl on the "save messsage as" window, the complete email si copied.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible way for you to achieve this would be by exporting the message to PDF by going to `File -> Print` and then selecting `Print to file`.